# Allure 2 Report generation - without Jenkins or Maven. Is there a set of API and documentation?

Tags: allure

I have a project that I am using Allure command line tool to generate reports from a set of result files. I would like to explore if there is a way that we can "programmatically" generate the reports? I am not using Jenkins or Maven to run tests. 
Any idea and suggestions? 
Thank you in advance.

M.

Comment: What do you mean when say "programmatically"?

Comment: I meant calling an API at end of test runs, instead of using locally installed report binary, and command line

Comment: Which automation tool are you using?

Comment: We have automated test mainly in Java and we upload result files to a storage. The results needs to be polled to a server where allure reports to be generated. Is this what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight way to generate report programmatically. But you can review allure cli source code and add it as library to your test. But don’t see any reasons to do that.

Comment: Thanks, that may be the route i would take.